# Probability of timing

Tags: probability-theory

Tigger and kanga plan to meet at the gym, but will each independently arrive at a uniformly random time between 14:00 and 15:00. Tigger is willing to wait 24 minutes for Kanga before leaving, but Kanga is only willing to wait 6 minutes for tigger before leaving. What is the probability they end up meeting eachother ?

Comment: Variants of this have been asked many times on this site.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498359/probability-of-meeting) for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic probability: Romeo and Juliette meet for a date.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279873/basic-probability-romeo-and-juliette-meet-for-a-date)